# Not enough right margin for the tags on tag pages (on iPadOS)

Tags: bug, tags, design, ios

I’ve marked only the most obvious situations on the picture:

> [image]

As you can see the rectangular background part of tags is too small for tag name.

Tested on iPadOS 13.2.2 in Chrome browser